# RuntimeError: Found no NVIDIA driver on your system. //Pretraining phase error

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, torch, amd-processor

The above error showed while working on a deep learning project. The project needs to work on huge image dataset. The python code was run with a pre-trained model, which has CUDA dependencies. I am unable to resolve this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\train.py", line 272, in <module>
    train(backbone, Image_size)
  File "D:\train.py", line 113, in train
    model = model.cuda()
  File "C:\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 688, in cuda
    return self._apply(lambda t: t.cuda(device))
  File "C:\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 578, in _apply
    module._apply(fn)
  File "C:\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 578, in _apply
    module._apply(fn)
  File "C:\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 601, in _apply
    param_applied = fn(param)
  File "C:\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 688, in <lambda>
    return self._apply(lambda t: t.cuda(device))
  File "C:\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\torch\cuda\__init__.py", line 216, in _lazy_init
    torch._C._cuda_init()
RuntimeError: Found no NVIDIA driver on your system. Please check that you have an NVIDIA GPU and installed a driver from http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx
```

Methods tried:

1. installation of pytorch-directML

The system specification is

OS: Windows
GPU: AMD Radeon HD 7000 series

Is there a way I can set GPU to **AMD**? Open to all suggestion for the same.

Thank you.

Comment: Please include error in body of question instead of screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

Since your machine does not have a CUDA-capable device, you cannot run the project with CUDA. You must run the project on the CPU instead.
You should remove all `.cuda()` calls in the source code.

Comment: The dataset we are working on is of images with around 512GB size. Is there any alternative  to use for CUDA?

Comment: There is no solution to run Pytorch without CUDA on your GPU. You can try Pytorch with ROCm, but this computing platform may not support your GPU.